# Trouble with subset() in R returning incorrect values

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am attempting to subset a region of genetic data by its chromosome and position information. Unfortunately, my results are not within my parameters. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
    subset.by.region<- function(df,region.info, expansion=0){
     MBstart = as.numeric(region.info[[3]]) - expansion
     MBend = as.numeric(region.info[[4]]) + expansion
     chrom =as.numeric(region.info[[2]])
     print(chrom)
     print(MBstart)
     print(MBend)
     BPstart <- MBstart  * 1e6
     BPend <- MBend  * 1e6
     sub_results <- as.numeric(df$CHR) == chrom & as.numeric(df$BP) >= BPstart & as.numeric(df$BP) <= BPend;
     print(head(sub_results))
     region_results <- subset(results, sub_results)
     return(region_results)
    }
```

Here are the prints to the console containing the region information being used:

```
[1] 1
[1] 113.308
[1] 115.158
```

Here is the print from the subset (region_results):

```
     GENE CHR     SNP    EMP1  NP        BP          SNP_IM  SNP_LZ
3238 AP3S1   5    rs26538 1.00000   6 115178395         rs26538    rs26538
3239 AP4B1   1  rs1217401 1.00000  46 114438951 imm_1_114240474  rs1217401
3240 AP4B1   1  rs1217402 1.00000  41 114440258 imm_1_114241781  rs1217402
3241 AP4B1   1  rs3789613 1.00000 297 114443035 imm_1_114244558  rs3789613
3242 AP4B1   1  rs7523862 1.00000 297 114443419 imm_1_114244942  rs7523862
3243 AP4B1   1 rs17464525 1.00000 148 114443899 imm_1_114245422 rs17464525
```

As you can see, there is a row in the subset containing a marker in chromosome 5. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.
edit:
Here is the call to the function with the stuff before it:

```
     write.genelist <- function(table_loc, region.info, out_folder,yank_loc){
      region.ID = as.character(region.info[[1]])
      out_name = paste0(region.ID,"_genes.list")
      region_folder = file.path(out_folder, region.ID)
      out_loc <- file.path(region_folder,out_name, fsep = .Platform$file.sep)
      results <- read.table(table_loc, T,strip.white = TRUE)
      gene_region_results <- subset.by.region(results,region.info)
      ...
     }
```

Comment: Please show the call to your subset function as well as the contents of  region.info.

Comment: It's very odd that sub_reslts is not a logical (Boolean) vector.  You should look into that.

Comment: Post the output of str(region.info) (or rather the object you passed to the region.info parameter when you made the call to your function.) Console output is generally ambiguous, as your offering demonstrates. Use `str` and `dput` to improve communication.

Comment: If your trouble is in chrom matching, please remove all other code.  Also WHAT subset printing?

Comment: I think you need to read `?subset` which warns you off using `subset()` for programming. It uses the standard non-standard evaluation rules to look things up and that can go all sorts of wrong when used inside your own function. For starters, it is trying to find `results` which looks like it is in the global workspace but use `sub_results` which is in the executing environment of the function. Use `[` instead.

Comment: Odd, I have never (noticeably) encountered a problem with `subset` in a function.

Comment: @AlexBrown It can work, but R Core advise against using it in such circumstances. It is really user sugar and `[` works fine everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `[` to subset in a function not `subset()`. See `?subset` for why.

```
subset.by.region<- function(results, df, region.info, expansion=0){
    MBstart = as.numeric(region.info[[3]]) - expansion
    MBend = as.numeric(region.info[[4]]) + expansion
    chrom =as.numeric(region.info[[2]])
    print(chrom)
    print(MBstart)
    print(MBend)
    BPstart <- MBstart  * 1e6
    BPend <- MBend  * 1e6
    sub_results <- as.numeric(df$CHR) == chrom & 
        as.numeric(df$BP) >= BPstart & as.numeric(df$BP) <= BPend
    print(head(sub_results))
    results[sub_results, ]
}
```

I would also pass in `results` not rely on it being found in the global environment.

Comment: Thanks so much! I transplanted the code into its own function and missed that I had altered from "results" to the more general df. I would mark up, but my reputation is too low. I will look into using [ instead as per your advice.

Comment: @user1636450 You can certainly accept an answer even with 1 rep point.

Comment: Thank you! I admit I am such a noob, that I didn't even realize that was my next step. Thank you DWin.

Comment: Looks like results is the bug.

Comment: @AlexBrown Yeah, wasn't sure what was intended by the OP hence my comment in the Answer.